# Android Device Monitor can't send GPS data to emulator, but it works manually

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, android-emulator, android-device-monitor

I recently switched to Android Studio 2.0. Before that I was able to send GPX files to the emulator through ADM's Emulator control tab. Since the switching, that feature seems to be broken. I am currently able to connect through `telnet` and manually send geo fixes (not easy to simulate long tracks this way), but ADM refuses to let me set a GPX file, a manual location or a KML file. Buttons are enabled but I can't click other them.

I should say, that ADM is correctly connected to the device, since I was able to parse file system, etc.

Any hint on what's happening? Any workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?